# ios apple app review rejection for location feature is not integrated with the built-in mapping functionality

Tags: ios, flutter, dictionary

We request for your kind support, whether it is a previous experience or even a comment will help us a lot!

[ios app rejection comment for using google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb6hZ.png)

Our app requires POI(point of interest) on google maps for the service, thus, utilizing apple map's data causes disruption and mismatch of POI data causes issues on business logic (If our app's function was just loading apple map with marker on it, we could solve the issue..)

Has anyone faced this rejection issue? We look forward to your kind comment...

We searched libraries supporting apple map on flutter but there are only 2 and it doesn't support the functions we need.

Comment: You can use Google's map view in your app, but if you provide an option to link out to the Google maps app then you must also provide an option to link out to the Apple Maps app.  The reason is that if a user doesn't have Google Maps installed then the user will not be able to open it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your reply, we don't provide an option to link out to the google map. We just show user's current location and POIs around it, if the user touches the POI => the title of the place appears. Would the rejection due to misunderstanding of the function from the review team?

Comment: Maybe. Your app can't require another app (e.g. Google Maps) to be installed in order to function, but as far as I know there is no requirement that you use Apple's map view rather than Google's

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you once again for reply, now we are facing appstoreconnect error..which seemed to have been solved..anyways, thank you once again!